# TensorFlow.jl output shape of dynamic_rnn

Tags: tensorflow, julia, lstm

- Julia 0.6.0
- TensorFlow.jl 0.7.5
- tensorflow (python) 1.4.1
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I am setting up an LSTM for time series prediction. I need the outputs for every time-step, as I want to calculate loss not only for the last time-step. According to the [documentation of tensorflow (Python API)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), the outputs of `dynamic_rnn` should have shape `[batch_size, max_time, cell.output_size]` (if `time_major == False`).

In python, this works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 3
series_length = 10
hidden_size = 7
number_of_features = 2

session = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, series_length, number_of_features])

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

o = session.run(outputs, feed_dict={x: np.random.randn(batch_size, series_length, number_of_features)})
```

`outputs` has shape `[3, 10, 7]`, which agrees with `[batch_size, series_length, hidden_size]`.

Now, I can use a dense layer to output a single value y at every time-step.

When I use TensorFlow.jl, `outputs` has shape `[3, 7]` which corresponds to `[batch_size, hidden_size]`. This seems to be only the last time-step.

```
using TensorFlow
tf = TensorFlow

batch_size = 3
series_length = 10
number_of_features = 2
hidden_size = 7

session = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(Float32, shape=[-1, series_length, number_of_features])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x)

run(session, global_variables_initializer())

o = run(session, [outputs], Dict(x=>rand(Float32, batch_size, series_length, number_of_features)))
```

Does someone understand if this is intentionally, a bug or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.
TensorFlow.jl's `dynamic_rnn`, unlike Python TensorFlow's `dynamic_rnn`,
only returns the output and state at the end of the final step.

This is because TensorFlow.jl doesn't have great support for the creation of dynamically sized tensors at runtime. 
There are ways, but they are not currently being employed for this.
I think python uses [TensorArrays](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray),
which we currently just don't have.

The easy solution is to not use a `dynamic_rnn`.

The TensorFlow.jl static RNN i.e. `TensorFlow.nn.rnn` has basically the same interface, but returns the output at every time-step.

I have noted this down in the [issues](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/353).